# Display names in dropdown in webpart property

Tags: web-part, web-part-property

I would like to add custom property that offers a list of choices.

It is possible to use Enum type. The property will be then rendered as a combobox.

```
public enum Group
    {
        GroupA,
        GroupB,
        GroupC
    }

[WebBrowsable(true), 
Category("Miscellaneous"), 
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
WebDisplayName("Group name")]
public Group SelectedGroup
{
get { return _group;  }
set { _group = value;}
}
```

It works fine - but I would like to use more complex group names like "John Doe's group". 
Is there any way to do that? I haven't found anything and I'd prefer not to create EditorPart and do all those things manually.

Comment: You can implement a type-safe enum pattern : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-sharp-string-enums/424414#424414

Answer (score 3):

Enums in .Net can have spaces with System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute.
Your example could be rewritten like this:

```
public enum Group
{
    [Description("John Doe's Group")]
    GroupA,
    [Description("Frank Star's Group")]
    GroupB,
    [Description("Stella Reinolds Group")]
    GroupC
}
```

Then using reflection you could access Description property

```
public static string GetGroupEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo group= value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute[] descAttr= (DescriptionAttribute[])group.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(descAttr), false);

    if (descAttr!= null && descAttr.Length > 0) {
        return descAttr[0].Description;
    }
    else {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you will use this method `GetGroupEnumDescription(Group.GroupA);`

Putting this all together to populate your DropDownList you could use

```
foreach (Group group in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Group)))
{
    groupDropDown.Items.Add(GetGroupEnumDescription(group));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then I would have to create Editor Part and render dropdown manually, right? I'm wondering if its possible to do this [that way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174(v=office.11).aspx) by simply adding the property to webpart. Enums are rendered as a dropdown, but this dropdown is populated by enum's values' names - I haven't found any "Display Name". It doesn't support Description Attribute as well. Well, maybe the only solution is to make an Editor Part and populate the dropdown manually like you said...

Comment: I think that the easiest way to achieve this is to create a webpart with a dropdownlist and in the editor part select the Enum to be populated. Each Enum will have its own values. And I made a proof of concept and it works

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's a pity that there is no such a functionality out of the box...